# Game design urn problem

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference, hypergeometric-distribution

I am designing a tabletop game and trying to conceptualise the probabilities involved. These can be expressed as an urn problem:

Our urn contains seven counters, either green or red. We draw five and observe their colour. I am interested in the degree to which a player, based on this (and potential subsequent similar observations), could be certain there are no red counters left in the urn.

I have calculated the probabilities of selecting 0-5 red counters based on the number that are in the urn (using the =HYPGEOM.DIST function in Excel) as per the below table:

[image: Stats Table (5 from 7)]

Where my stats knowledge runs out is that I am interested in the confidence a player may have that there are no red counters left in the urn (not having any knowledge how many red counters were in there to start with - they know there a 7 in total). My first thought was to calculate the probability there were 0, OR 1, OR 2 red counters left (the only three options as 5 of 7 have been drawn) but it doesn't seem to make sense when I try to apply this.

Obviously I am interested in looking at multiple draws, but as far as I can tell calculating this is fairly straightforward if I can do it for one. The aim is to have a way to express a desired percentage confidence (per draw) that there are no red counters left in the urn. For example if I want the player to have a ~33% confidence for one draw ~66% for two and ~99% for three I can use the maths to calculate I need to draw, for example, 4 from 7, then 5 from 7, then another 5 from 7.

I am aware I may be overcomplicating this and have considered if looking at it in terms of p-values may be a better approach? There is clearly a lot available on urn problems, but I haven't found anything that looks at them from the perspective of confidence in a negative.

Thank you for reading and any help offered is greatly appreciated.

J

Comment: I suggest looking into Bayes' Theorem. To calculate the probability that the urn now contains no red counters, the player needs a prior distribution on how many red counters were in the urn to begin with. E.g. if the player thinks that there are probably 7 red counters in the urn, and then withdraws 5 red counters, their confidence that the red counters are all gone will be lower than it would be if they initially thought the urn probably contained only 5 red counters.